# User privileges for files on DAS drive connected to multiple servers

Tags: storage

If a DAS drive is mounted on several servers can we still control privileges of server-specific user accounts on the files/folders on the DAS drive?

ex: on both Server1 and Server2 DAS drive has been mounted as /data now User1 of Server1 writes to /data a file called file1.

And later User2 on Server2 looks up permissions on file1, it seems that he would see some userid(a number) as owner of the file when he does "ls -al" and sometimes it does prevent him from accessing/writing the file.

I am confused as to how can we apply/ensure consistent permissions on files in DAS especially when it is being parallelly accessed by several users on several systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SAN Block level device shared between multiple servers you need to have an application that knows how to address that and not cause problems.

This could be Virtualization software like VMWare or HyperV, clustering software, or a filesystem that knows how to handle that. With that in mind, if you had the right application on the SAN drive you can control privileges.

It is also possible that you are asking about a NAS (Network attached storage) where there is already a filesystem on the shared storage. In this case yes you can control specific privileges by user depending on what NAS software features are supported.

Comment: Thanks Praxum, I have created this question a long while ago and realized a little later that it was actually DAS not SAN. correct it now.